# ESLint rule for camelCased argument names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lint, eslint

I want to use camelCase function argument names:

```
myFunc(goodArg, BadArg) {
    ...
}
```

I found ESLint's [camelcase](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase) rule. Unfortunately it does not apply to argument names, just variables and properties.

Is there a way to automatically just function argument names? I don't mind using another linter if it helps.

Comment: I believe it would be relatively easy to create your own lint rule: http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules .

Comment: You'll use those arguments in the functions and those will be checked, won't they? Doesn't seem necessary to check the arg names too. If there's an issue it will be caught.

Comment: No warning when I use them. Otherwise this wouldn't be an issue...

Comment: Arguments *do* get checked. (try renaming `goodArg` to `good_arg`) However, the camelcase rule only checks that there isn't an underscore (`_`) in the the variable name (source: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/camelcase.js). What you want to check is that the leading letter isn't an uppercase letter. There's no such rule afaik. However, it can be tricky to implement as you might want to allow variable names starting with uppercase letters in some circumstances (e.g constructors such as `new SomethingNice`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with uppercase parameter names, signifying that you expect to get passed a class/constructor.