# Eslint CamelCase with lowercase

Tags: javascript, eslint, lowercase, camelcasing

I'm looking for a Eslint rule that allows me to do this:

```
this.Id = 1; // error
this.id = 1; // correct
```

Im already using the camelcase rule but only verifies against underscores.

"camelcase": ["error", {"properties": "always"}]

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777168/eslint-rule-for-camelcased-argument-names

Comment: Is implementing the rule from scratch the only solution that i have? Technically there is nothing wrong with the first capital letter